# Maven could not resolve dependencies for project : No versions available for org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:[2.0,3) within specified range

Tags: java, maven, build, owasp, esapi

Before marking this question as duplicate, let me tell you this question is a bit different.

I have a project with three modules, namely **-ejb**, **-ear** and **-web** on NetBeans. I am currently working on the **-web** module, and till last night everything was working fine and I made my `git commit` on a working project after which I did a **clean and build** on my project which failed to build since my internet connection was down. Since I am using **ESAPI** from **OWASP**, it needs to download a few dependencies each time while building, and since my internet connection was down, it failed to build.

Today, when I tried to do a **clean and build** with a working internet connection, the **-web** module is giving me errors about maven dependencies.

> Failed to execute goal on project Papercraft-web: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.onclave.papercraft:Papercraft-web:war:0.00.09.00-METIS: Failed to
>   collect dependencies for
>   [org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE (compile),
>   ...
>   org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.1.0.1 (compile),
>   javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 (provided)]: No versions available for
>   org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:[2.0,3) within specified range -> [Help 1]

So the problem is with the `esapi` dependency. From other related posts from SO, I found out that if I provide an exact version as a dependency, that might solve the problem, so I did mention the exact dependency as **[1.2]** which is available at maven central. Now, if I do a **clean and build**, maven fails again, but this time with:

> Failed to execute goal on project Papercraft-web: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.onclave.papercraft:Papercraft-web:war:0.00.09.00-METIS: Failed to
>   collect dependencies for
>   [org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE (compile),
>   ...
>   org.owasp.encoder:encoder-esapi:jar:[1.2,1.2] (compile),
>   org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:[2.1.0.1,2.1.0.1] (compile),
>   javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 (provided)]: No versions available for
>   org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:[2.0,3) within specified range -> [Help 1]

So, it did find the correct version of **esapi**, i.e., `1.2` but it is giving the same error. I have no idea what is happening here. What am I missing?

This is the dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
            <artifactId>encoder-esapi</artifactId>
            <version>[1.2]</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have two questions regarding this,

1. How do I solve the problem?
2. The project is under development for the past 3 months with about 150+ commits and this error never showed up though **ESAPI** was added at a very early stage and every build worked without a problem. What made this error jump out all of a sudden?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your artifact & group is not matching
 either use

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.encoder/encoder -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
<artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or use

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
<artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.1</version> <!-- check for other versions too, 1.x is not available -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: You really saved me a lot of trouble. Thank you. Just the other question, this dependency was declared like this from the very beginning, like I said, any idea why the error never showed up earlier?